# Test XML content without using mock mvc

Tags: xml, spring, unit-testing, xpath, spring-test

I am using spring test with mockmvc and it works like a charm to test xml output!

Example:

```
ResultActions actions = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/entry/NX_P38398/overview.xml"));
actions.andExpect(xpath("entry/overview/gene-name-list/gene-name[@type='recommended']").exists());
actions.andExpect(xpath("entry/overview/gene-name-list/gene-name[@type='recommended']").string("BRCA1"));
```

I would like to take advantage of the same features to test an OutputStream without using mockmvc and controllers.
Is it possible to use the same ResultMatcher?

Example (pseudo code):

```
XMLContent xmlContent = new XMLContent("<entry>...</entry>");
AssertTrue(xmlContent.andExpect(xpath("entry/overview/gene-name-list/gene-name[@type='recommended']").exists());
```

I know it exists XMLUnit http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/ar01s05.html or other libraries, but I would like to re-use the same ResultMatcher.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to reuse `XpathResultMatchers` without `MockMvc` and related classes.

However... the code in question (in your pseudo-code example), delegates internally to Spring's `XpathExpectationsHelper`. So you can invoke -- for example -- the `exists()` method directly on an instance of `XpathExpectationsHelper` if you so desire.

As an alternative, you could write your own simple assertions based on XPath using `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` which is what `XpathExpectationsHelper` uses internally anyway. Or... as you mentioned, just use the built-in support for XPath in XMLUnit.